# How to set different directory for visitors and admins?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I wrote this script, but loading freezes at `return express.static`.

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

var check_token = jwt({
    secret: 'MY_SECRET',
    credentialsRequired: false
});

var dir;

app.use(check_token, function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        dir = '/public';
        next();
    } else {
        dir = '/private';
        next();
    }
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(__dirname + dir);
    return express.static(__dirname + dir);
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log(__dirname + dir);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, dir, 'index.html'));
});
```

When I wrote this, I can't get `css`, `js` from directory. I got `index.html`, only.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + dir));
```

I don't understand, how fix it. Help me, please :)

Comment: What lib are you using? JWT?

Comment: @MayorMonty express-jwt

Comment: `js` and `css` are directories, yes? In your static inclusion instruction, did you include these directories